# Operator for Multiple Points in One Struct

Tags: c++, algorithm, struct, operator-keyword

I have a struct that stores two points that should be interchangeable.

```
struct Edge
{
    unsigned short firstIndex;
    unsigned short secondIndex;
    Edge(unsigned short firstIndex, unsigned short secondIndex) :
        firstIndex(firstIndex), secondIndex(secondIndex) {}
};
```

The `operator==` method should be as follows (To make them interchangeable)

```
bool operator == (const Edge& e2) const
{
    return 
        first == e2.first && second == e2.second || 
        first == e2.second && second == e2.first;
}
```

**I am looking to create an `operator<` and `operator>` method in order to use the struct in a `std::map`**

I have tried the following (using multiplication) but it does not work since there are many cases in which different edges return the same value

```
bool operator < (const Edge& e2) const
{
    return first * second < e2.first * e2.second;
}
```

The code that I would like to use is the following:

```
std::map<Edge, unsigned int> edgePoints;
Edge e1(0, 1);
Edge e2(1, 2);
Edge e3(2, 0);

edgePoints[e1] = 2;
edgePoints[e2] = 0;
edgePoints[e3] = 1;
```

Although the code does not work with my `operator<` method because `0 * 1 == 2 * 0` so the map returns `2` when I call `edgePoints[e3]`

**Does anyone know of an `operator<` and `operator>` method that I could use or even some other way of mapping the edges in order to use the `std::map`**

Comment: You can use an `unordered_map` instead, if you provide a hash function for your `Edge` type

Comment: That seems like what I want although what should my hash function be?

Comment: If first < second integer(second, first) Else integer(fist, second)

Comment: Boost has a hash_combine function you could use (or steal) : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html

Comment: I'd prefer not to use boost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would store the indices of the edge in such a way, that the smaller index always is the first index. It looks like the internal representation is irrelevant in your application. You don't need `operator==` for maps. Here is the example struct:

```
struct Edge
{
    typedef unsigned short Idx; // prefer strong typedef cf boost
    Edge(Idx a, Idx b) 
    :
        firstIndex(std::min(a, b)),
        secondIndex(std::max(a, b))
    {}

    Idx firstIndex;
    Idx secondIndex;

    bool operator<(Edge const & other)
    {
        if (firstIndex != other.firstIndex) 
            return firstIndex < other.firstIndex;
        return secondIndex < other.secondIndex;
    }
}; // Edge
```

If you want to make your implementation even nicer, some minor suggestions:

- Prefer `std::array<unsigned short, 2>` over separate variables `firstIndex` and `secondIndex`. Doing so allows iterating over the indices.
- If you are using `array`, you can shorten the `operator<` using [`std::lexicographical_compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare).

Comment: There is no compiler-generated `operator==`. And you don't need it for `std::map` anyway.

Comment: Side note: std::tie(firstIndex, secondIndex) <  std::tie(other.firstIndex, other.secondIndex)

Comment: @m8mble that's really a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider compairing them as sorted pairs.

```
bool operator < (const Edge& e2) const
{
    if (min(first, second) != min(e2.first, e2.second))
        return min(first, second) < min(e2.first, e2.second);
    return max(first, second) < max(e2.first, e2.second);
}
```

Edit: Of course that can be written nicelier with saving mins and maxes as local variables, but the idea should be clear.

Edit: The idea in other answer is better: force your struct to always have first less then second, and it will eliminate all mins and maxes, and make comparation run fast like hell)

Comment: This seems to be working with the tests that I have done. Let me do some more tests before I mark it as correct.

Comment: This answer is slower than the one I have provided. I don't think it matters for small testing. But I wouldn't use it for large graph instances.

Comment: @m8mble But it preserves the information, if an edge is going from A to B or B to A (which might be required)

Comment: It preserves information that was described to be "interchangeable". If think we are dealing with undirected edges here.